# TortoiseHG, --debug switch

Tags: tortoisehg

I'm using windows 3.1.1 x64 of TortoiseHG on two machines which unexpectedly execute hg with different switches when performing actions via TortoiseHG's GUI.

On machine (A)

```
% hg pull --verbose --debug ssh://hg@server/repo
```

On machine (B)

```
% hg pull --verbose ssh://hg@server/repo
```

I can't work out how to control the hg command line switches that TortoiseHG uses.  In this case specifically to disable the "--debug" flag on machine (A).

I understand that this is Tortoise that determines the command to run, so I've been looking for Tortoise configuration files and the registry for settings - no luck.

I've also checked the usual mercurial locations;
  - the users mercurial.ini, 
  - the repositories hgrc,
  - TortoiseHG/hgrc.d/mercurial.rc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sync Toolbar` (1) - `Synchronize` button (2) - `Options` button (3) - `Emit debugging output` checkbox in window (4)

[image: Sync options]